# Apply different CSS style on wrapping

Tags: javascript, css, html

I can't for the life of me think of where to start here - basically what I want to achieve is a three column row, in which the columns can wrap below each other if they cannot fit horizontally. The height of the row should be the smallest to fit the items, with a fixed height when all the cells are in line. The contents of the "cells" should be centered vertically if the row is too large for them eg:

```
[           ] [ Big     ] [           ]
[  Content1 ] [         ] [ Content2  ]
[           ] [ Content ] [           ]
```

Should wrap something like...

```
[           ] [ Big     ]
[  Content1 ] [         ] 
[           ] [ Content ]
      [ Content2  ]
```

Then...

```
[  Content1 ] 
 [ Big     ]
 [         ] 
 [ Content ]
[ Content2  ]
```

The issue I'm running into is.. how can I shrink/grow the height of the "cells" to be the greater of their own content and their horizontal neighbours content?

The best idea I've had is to use JS to look at the offsetHeight to determine if they are on the same "row", then adjust the height accordingly.. but it seems a little clunky. Any better ideas?

Thanks guys!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

```css
.row {
    display: inline-flex;
    flex-flow: row wrap;
    justify-content: center;
}

.row div {
    border: 1px solid;
    margin: .5em;
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: column;
    justify-content: center;
}

p {
    margin: .5em;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
    <div>
        <p>Content 1</p>
    </div>
    <div>
        <p>Big</p>
        <p>Content</p>
    </div>
    <div>
        <p>Content 1</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

(see [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SelenIT/dtfys5g7/))

Comment: Beautiful - just.. beautiful :) I'll have to read up on flex-flow/inline-flex etc.. as I haven't played with them before, but this does exactly what I wanted without any JS. Thanks mate!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `display:inline-block` on each of those containing divs. that will make the height expand to the tallest div and it will wrap like you described

Comment: Thanks for replying, though unless I'm missing something.. this doesn't appear to be the case [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/v3wjtqxf/)

Comment: @Ilya's answer (using flex box) is a better solution. Flexbox gives you more layout control for future changes you might want to make.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this code, it will help you...

```
.selector {

display:inline-flex;
justify-content:center;
max-width:(expected width);
max-height:(expected height);
width:100%;
height:100%;
margin:auto;

}
```

Comment: Thanks for replying, but this doesn't seem to work either.. The heights are only set if the parent container has an explicit height set on it, and if that's the case, the smaller blocks don't "shrink" when they wrap either. [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7gev60dt/2/)

Comment: Thanks, but still no dice, If you force the "big content" element to be larger (eg. by inserting a break), the other elements on the same row do not grow to match the size. llya's answer does the trick perfectly if you're interested